# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'userId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32

Tags: c#

[image]

[image]

This is the error that I encounter, which is confusing because it works just a while ago. I accidentally clicked some buttons and this happened. I am creating a "delete" function for a simple system I'm currently doing..

And the other error is outputted saying:

> "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'userId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Here is my code:

**UserController.cs**

```
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
        {
            UserBusinessLayer userService = new UserBusinessLayer("sqlconn");

            UserModel userModel = new UserModel();

            try
            {
                UserEntity userEntity = userService.GetUserId(id);


                userModel.usr_Id = userEntity.usr_Id;
                userModel.email = userEntity.email;
                userModel.username = userEntity.username;
                userModel.password = userEntity.password;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

            return View(userModel);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteUser")]
        public ActionResult DeleteUserConfirmed(int id)
        {
            UserBusinessLayer userService = new UserBusinessLayer("sqlconn");

            userService.DeleteUser(new UserEntity(){

                usr_Id = id
            });

            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
```

**UserBusinessLayer.cs**

```
 public UserEntity DeleteUser(int userId)
        {

            UsersDataAccess userService = new UsersDataAccess(_key);

            try
            {
                return userService.DeleteUser(userId);
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {

                throw exx;
            }

        }
```

**UserDataAccess.cs**

```
public UserEntity DeleteUser(int userId) {

            SqlConnection oCon = null;
            SqlCommand oCmd = null;
            UserEntity user = null;

            try
            {
                oCon = _connection.openConn();
                string sqlDelete = string.Format("DELETE FROM Users WHERE usr_id = @userId");

                oCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlDelete, oCon);
                oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userId", user.usr_Id));
                oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

            return user;
        }
```

Comment: Would you share the request too ?

Comment: what request? @Rainman

Comment: Seems like you sent empty value of Id while calling the controller.

Comment: You are applying a request to "DeleteUserConfirmed" action and the Id parameter isn't passed.

Comment: I see.. what should I do??? What part of the code do I fix?

Comment: What's the value of `user.usr_Id`, and how you pass `id` parameter to `DeleteUserConfirmed` method? Seems that you've missing `id` parameter when POST-ing view.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed by adding a try catch block. Thanks for all your help.

[image]

Comment: Kenny, hiding an error, does not fix it. In other words: seeing no exception, does not mean, the user is deleted.

Comment: First of all I don't know how it fixes your problem, because you `throw` the exception. Secondly this is a terrible way to hide an exception and someone will have to pay for it sooner or later.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the name of action parameter.

Your controller exposes the `DeleteUserConfirmend` action as

```
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
```

But since the error is concerned about `userId` not being filled, this probably means a mismatch between the route parameters (I guess the route for this action has a parameter named `userId`) and the name of the parameter of your method.

Try renaming `id` to `userId` in your method like this:

```
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int userId)
```